# Shared memory in multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading

The program is to count the number of vowels in the string using threads.

counter=number of threads.

Number of vowels is maintained in a DictionaryEntry and is being  accessed by multiple threads. Caps and small letters are combined together.
coding is as per the below sample input and output.

O/P:

Enter Number of Counters :
2

Enter text for counter 1 :
Everbody gota learn some time

Enter text for counter 2 :
One,Two,Three,Four,Five,Six,Seven,Eight,Nine,Ten

Vowels count in given text are :
a:2 e:14 i:5 o:6 u:1

My program so far:

class Program

```
{

    public static Dictionary<char, int> h = new Dictionary<char, int>();

    static void count(int s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter text for counter {0} :", s);
        string str = Console.ReadLine();
        char[] c = str.ToCharArray();
        int n = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < c.Length; i++)
        {
            if ((char.ToLower(c[i]) == 'a') || (char.ToLower(c[i]) == 'e') || (char.ToLower(c[i]) == 'i') || (char.ToLower(c[i]) == 'o') || (char.ToLower(c[i]) == 'u'))
            {
                if (!h.ContainsKey(c[i]))
                {
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < c.Length; j++)
                    {

                        if (c[i] == c[j])
                        {
                            n++;
                        }

                    }
                    h.Add(c[i], n);
                }
                n = 1;
            }
        }
        foreach (var v in h.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", v, h[v]);
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int s=0;
        count(s);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(() => count(i + 1));
            t1.Start();
            t1.Join();
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your current program will have issues on account of taking input from Console for each thread, it will not be the most elegant way to take the input, I would suggest following changes:

- Pass input as a part of ThreadStart delegate, even better create a collection of all inputs and use parallel foreach

Now your dictionary will break due to Multi-thread access, use following instead

```
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>
```

Certainly your call to API will change to TryAdd, as with all Concurrent Data structures